# Disjoint sets in a Euclidean space

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $E_x, E_x'$ be arbitrarily neighborhoods of $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. For any closed subset $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ let $S_{E_x'}\triangleq S-E_x'$, where '-' indicates set-theoretic difference.
Is it true that $S_{E_x'}$ and $E_x$ are disjoint?
I don't think so because $E_x, E_x'$ are arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the intuition that this is false, you should look for a counterexample.

Let $n=1$, $x=0$, $E_x = [-2;2]$, $E_x'=[-1;1]$, $S=[0;2]$

then $S_{E_x'}=]1;2]$
and you see that $S_{E_x'}$ and $E_x$ are not disjoint since $S_{E_x'} \cap E_x = ]1;2] \ne\emptyset$